# Why does Body Mass Index computation result in an incorrect result?

Tags: java

I did the following program, but my output does not match with the book answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI_Index {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter weght in pound: ");
        double pound = kbd.nextDouble();
        double kg = pound * 0.45359237;
        System.out.print("Enter hight in inches: ");
        double inches = kbd.nextDouble();
        double meters = inches * 0.0254;
        double BMI = kg/(inches * inches);
        System.out.println("BMI is " + BMI);
        if (BMI < 18.5) {
            System.out.print("Underweight");
        }
        if (BMI >= 18.5 && BMI < 25.0) {
            System.out.print("Normal");
        }
        if (BMI >= 25.0 && BMI < 30.0) {
            System.out.print("Overweight");
        }
        if (BMI >= 30.0) {
            System.out.print("Obese");
        }
    }
}
```

With this Code i get the output underneath:

```
Weight: 146 (inches)
Height: 70 (inches)
Result: 0.013515201228571428 (BMI)
```

Predicted Output by my Book is:

```
Weight: 146 (inches)
Height: 70 (inches)
Result: 20.948603801493316 (BMI)
```

Comment: What is the book answer and what do you get?

Comment: This is my output:  Enter weght in pound: 146
Enter hight in inches: 70
BMI is 0.013515201228571428
Underweight. Book out is Enter weght in pound: 146
Enter hight in inches: 70
BMI is 20.948603801493316
Normal

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
double BMI = kg/(inches * inches);
```

to

```
double BMI = kg/(meters * meters);
```

Comment: got it, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You must decide if you want to calculate the BMI in inches and pounds or in meters and kg.